# Drop some parts of video and re-make key frames (c++ + libav)

Tags: c, ffmpeg, libav, libavcodec, libavformat

I'm trying to drop some parts of video in my app using libav, for example in a video that has 00:08:00 length, I try to drop frames 100-250 and 400-500 (Just for example).
I wrote this code that copy AVPacket and drop some packets, But there is a problem! In our videos every keyframe followed by 29 non-key frames. So when my code goes to drop frames 100-250 the frame 100 may be is a non-key frame, in this case the parts that are going to join (In this example frame 250 to frame 400) the frame 400 is positioned after a keyframe that is not belogs to.

In this section video frames shown garbled,

Video cutting speed is so important in my code, so I can't decode/re-encode all of video frames.

The question is that, How can I decode encode begin of each parts (from begin frame to first key frame) and make another frames copy without decode?

Or, Is there any another **FAST** solution for splitting/merging (Dropping some parts of video)?

Comment: did you mean to use [tag:c++] instead of [tag:c]?

Comment: At the moment I'm using c, But language is not important. Every solution in any language is more that welcome.

Comment: What (container) format and what codec(s) are you using? Can you choose? If you can, then using intra-frames-only and/or adjusting GOP length may help.

Comment: AVPacket.flags & AV_PKT_FLAG_KEY tells you that a packet contains a keyframe, but I doubt it'll be as easy as that. Also beware of _forward_ references (B frames). Consider closed GOPs.

Answer (score 0):

```
The question is that, How can I decode encode begin of each parts (from  begin frame to first key frame) and make another frames copy without decode?
```

You can't. It doesn't work that way.

Comment: Is there other solution available? So let me ask clear; How can I cut some parts of video very fast? What is the fastest way? Decode/re-encoding is too slow

Answer (score 0):

Start to think about time, not in frames

you can get new videos fast in parts of base_video.mp4, for example,

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:00.000 -i base_video.mp4 -t 8.000 -c copy -strict -2 new_video_8seconds_fromstart.mp4
```

> **-ss** 00:00:00.000 is the time to start the new video
>
> **-t** is the duration in seconds and miliseconds, example, for 8 seconds of duration you have to use 8.000
>
> **-an** if you dont want audio
>
> **-strict -2** if for copy some files codecs like DTS

but if you want with re-encoding remove **-c copy** but it never will be fast!

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:00.000 -i base_video.mp4 -t 8.000 new_video_8seconds_fromstart.mp4
```

Comment: Thanks for answering; but some points, I Have to use frame number, and I am using this in my code, ffmpeg command can't help me; I'm looking for libav soluton, and the last point is that ffmpeg in this case can't split video file to more than one segment, I want to give it some parts (start-end) and split within them.